# Unifying Perspectives on Discrete/Continuous Differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, discrete-calculus

I was prompted by some recent readings, and also by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089363/when-can-we-modify-a-propto-b-adding-delta), to try to rectify the fact that my notions of discrete and continuous differentiation have slipped away from one another.

I'm most shaky on the discrete side. I think a discrete (directional) derivative can be defined by $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{||h||}$, which as best I can tell, is a quantity that is most comfortable when $f:A^n\to A^1$ is a function between affine spaces. (I am assuming the codomain has dimension 1 only for simplicity; presumably it is easy to extend this to a total derivative.) In that case we have that $\Delta f:A^n\to\Bbb R$

However, for the continuous derivative, I know that the derivative is most comfortable when $f:M^n\to M^1$ is a function on a manifold, and in that case $Df$ is a member of the tangent bundle $T_\bullet M^n$. I'm not terribly sure how to directionalize it to make the analogy exact, but maybe an inner product trick would work?

My question is: Do I have the correct understanding of a discrete derivative, and if so, why is an affine space the discrete analogue of a tangent bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful to review the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) of the total or Frechet derivative, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \| f(x + h) - f(x) - Df_x(h) \| }{ \|h\| } = 0$$
It is defined for maps between Banach (complete normed vector) spaces $f:V\to W$ and if exists it serves as  *linearisation* of $f$ at the point $x$, $Df:V\to W$, $Df\in \mathcal L(V,W)$. For finite dimensional spaces, in given bases, it is represented by Jacobian matrix (at each $x$).

In differential geometry the total derivative (pushforward) is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29) for smooth maps between manifolds $\varphi:M\to N$,and is found as a Frechet derivate in chosen coordinate charts.

In the special case $f:M\to \mathbb R$, $df$ is a member of *cotangent* bundle: at each $x\in M$ it's an element of the dual space, a 1-form, linear functional on the tangent space, such that when given a tangent it returns the rate of change of the function $f$ in that "direction".